# UITapGesture doesn't work as expected on Popup class

Tags: ios, swift, uitapgesturerecognizer

I create a `Popup class` to use in my app and I want to add a `UITapGestureRecognizer` to the black layer opacity, when the user touch outside of the popup this close automatically. But the gesture was not recognized. I show you my code of the `Popup class`

```
class Popup {

let supView : UIView!
let blackVoile = UIView()

init(superView viewToInsert : UIView){

    self.supView = viewToInsert

    build()
}

private func build(){
    blackVoile.frame = supView.bounds
    blackVoile.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.cgColor

    blackVoile.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    let closeGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.close))
    blackVoile.addGestureRecognizer(closeGesture)

}


func show(){
    supView.addSubview(blackVoile)
}

@objc func close(){
    print("close function")
    self.blackVoile.removeFromSuperview()
}
}
```

The `close func` was never called. And there is no other over layer above the `blackVoile UIView`

This is when I called my class :

```
let newPopup = Popup(superView : self.view)
newPopup.show()
```

I'm beginner so, maybe we can't add gesture to a class who are not have an UIView instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem with your `opacity`. If we make any `opacity` to `zero` then that view consider as a hidden. So, your `tapGesture` not working.

**Update**

```
var newPopup : Popup!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    newPopup = Popup(superView : self.view)
    newPopup.show()
}
```

Comment: Thanks to your reply. I delete the opacity effect and this still not working .. I add a new redView for test and add it the gesture, and this not working to.. I don't know why. Maybe because my Popup class has not an instance of the view or a delegate ?

Comment: what is `Popup` ? Can you please share your `init` method ?

Comment: @El-Burritos as per edited question - Now issue with your instance creation of `Popup`. Define at class level variable. because it's scope it's local so, method not calling.

Comment: @El-Burritos Welcome.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Your `supView` also needs to be userInteractionEnabled.